# Switch fetch mode with spring-data and jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a pretty large count of entity classes with lots of relationships between them. I'm using spring-data-jpa with hibernate. Almost all the fetch modes are set to lazy. I was wondering if there is a chance to get eager fetching for the first level and lazy for the next one.

Example:

```
class EntityA {
     EntityB propertyB;
}
class EntityB {
     EntityC propertyC;
}
```

When I load entity B directly I would like entity C to be fetched eagerly. If I load entity A I want only entity B fetched eagerly and entity C lazy.

I know this can be accomplished with specific queries but I would like to avoid writing queries for every single entity.

I hope I'm making sense here. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is (currently) not supported by Spring Data JPA and we already have a feature request for this.
I linked this discussion to the issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-466

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: I see this is now implemented in Spring Data, but doesn't rather take a complex approach ?? I would liked it to be `GroupInfo findByGroupNameFetchMembers(String name);`